# Check if user exists in Firebase database across multiple children nodes

Tags: java, android

I've a database like this

```
"Node" : {
    "Location_1" : {
      "ID1" : {
        "address" : "address1",
        "balance" : "20",
        "batch" : "xyz",
        .
        .
        .
        "studentID" : "ID1",
        "studentName" : "Username",
        "total" : "amount"
      }
    },
    "Location_2" : {
      "ID2" : {
        "address" : "address2",
        "balance" : "0",
        "batch" : "xyz",
        .
        .
        "studentID" : "ID2",
        "studentName" : "username",
        "total" : "amount"
      }
    }
    "Location_3" : {
      "ID3" : {
        "address" : "address3",
        "balance" : "0",
        "batch" : "xyz",
        .
        .
        "studentID" : "ID3",
        "studentName" : "username",
        "total" : "amount"
      }
    }
```

I'm able to check if the ID1 exists in a particular Location_1 using the code given below, but I'm unable to find if the ID1 exists across different Location_X id's.

```
String url = "https://firebaseURL/Node/";
url = url + Location_1;
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    databaseReference.child(ID1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID already present. Enter unique ID!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else { // not present, so go ahead and add
```

}

I tried using a function like this to check if the user is present in all the subNodes.

```
private boolean checkIfUserExists(String ID) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("Location_1");
    .
    .

    String url = "https://firebaseURL/Node/";
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    for(String s: arrayList){
    if(getUserExists())
        break;
    databaseReference.child(s).child(ID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    setUserExists(true);
            }
        }
```

But always the function getUserExists return false. So I end up adding a new user in different location or updating the user's info in the same location.
Please let me know how to proceed on checking the existence of the userID in all the locationIDs

Comment: Had to create a new usernode to store all the users while adding data to the other Location_ID node and check if reference of the usernode has the user present. This solutions works but unnecessarily had to create another database node.